# How to make Nuxt.js SSR with partially static pre-rendering pages

Tags: nuxt.js

There are a lot of information either on Nuxt SSR, or going full static, but I can't find any guide how to build a hybrid SSR with static pages together.

I'm building a website with Nuxt SSR, and I want to pre-render all product pages statically from a 10MB JSON file.

I found an [archived thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nuxt/comments/lx4ptb/comment/gpmmr0d/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), mentioned it's possible to create a middleware with the routes to be statically generated. I don't know how to achieve that, and hope I can get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to join the Nuxt Discord but this is how you could achieve it:
first note that this is not an official way of doing things and we'll have something better coming out very soon. but if you really need this a workaround is as follows:

- set `target: 'server'` (not static)
- run `nuxt build` to create your ssr bundle
- run `nuxt generate --no-build` (ideally set your routes via generate.routes in your nuxt config)
- copy the generated dist folder contents into your static folder (or serve directly from your web server config)
- `nuxt start`

Source: https://discord.com/channels/473401852243869706/473406004751499275/886642260677124166

Comment: Ah, nice... this helps a lot. It's like building 2 separate apps with one code base. When it said "something better coming out very soon", what does that mean? Is it Nuxt 3 will have a proper solution without separate build + generate?

Comment: @samchuang yep, you'll get probably a few new rendering modes!

Comment: Will this still work for Nuxt 3? I'm facing the same issue. `nuxt build` seems to ignore the `prerender` route rules (contra the docs), while `nuxt generate` gives me ONLY the prerendered routes (as documented).